# specifying icons in binding expression from code-behind file

Tags: data-binding, icons, nativescript, code-behind

In a NativeScript JavaScript Core project, I have a GridLayout that I need to move from statically-defined XML to dynamically-created from a code-behind file.  I have this particular label from the XML:

```
<Label class="{{ allSelected ? 'item-icon-undefined' : 'item-icon-selected' }}" 
 col="0" text="{{ allSelected ? '&#xf10c;' : '&#xf111;' }}" tap="onSelectAllTap" />
```

My problem is with the text attribute.  I started out with:

```
Let selector = new Label; 
selector.bind({
  targetProperty: "text",
  sourceProperty: "$value",
  expression: "allSelected ? '&#xf10c;' : '&#xf111;' ",
});
```

But the text shows the string itself, such as &#xf111;  OK, I've hit this before, so I added charFromCode's:

```
selector.bind({
  targetProperty: "text",
  sourceProperty: "$value",
  expression: "allSelected ? String.fromCharCode('0xf111') : String.fromCharCode('0xf10C') ",
});
```

But this yields the error message,

```
Error: Only identifier function invocations are allowed
```

OK, I figure I need to move the function calls outside the bind, so I used

```
  let circleSolid = String.fromCharCode('0xf111');
  let circleHollow = String.fromCharCode('0xf10C');
  selector.bind({
    targetProperty: "text",
    sourceProperty: "$value",
    expression: "allSelected ? circleHollow : circleSolid ",
  });
```

But with this, there's no error message and no output appears at all.  When I look at the elements when debugging, the text attribute is simply absent.  If I bypass the bind and try

```
selector.text = circleSolid;
```

Then I get the icon as expected.  And, if I replace the icons with simple text in the expression, that works as well.  So, how I can I specify icon values in a binding expression?

edit 7/29/2020

I realized this was likely a scoping issue and that the variables were not defined when the binding expression was ultimately evaluated.  I changed the two `let`'s to `var`'s and moved them to the top of the constructor, but no joy.

Thus it looks like I need a literal expression, but how can that be done for a unicode value in this context?  Values like '&#xf10c;' and '0xf10c' have already failed.  I also thought it might be a better of properly escaping the string, and maybe it is, but '\&#xf10c;' doesn't work either.

edit 7/29/2020, a few minutes later

The key word here was "escape."  I entered the hex values as escaped unicode characters (i.e., '\uf10c') and everything works as expected.  I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

See the edits, above.  In this context, the icon code points can be expressed as escaped unicode characters, such as '\uf10c'.